# WARNING: Passing multiple tags through @CucumberOptions is deprecated. Please use a single tag expressions?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, tag

I tried to run a Cucumber test with multiple tags.

But got this error.

I am using Cucumber version 5.7.0.

How can i run multiple tags now?

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)                
@CucumberOptions
(
        features = {"src/main/java/com/project1/features"},
        glue = {"com/project1/stepDefinitions"},
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        tags = {"@User1Login", "@User2Login"},
        monochrome = true
        )
```

Comment: There is an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406598/cucumber-multiple-tags-not-running-the-scenarios See if that still works.

Answer (score 4):

In Cucumber 5.7.0 the support of tags is handled in different way so that expression(infix boolean expression) can also be used in the same way.
You can pass the multiple tags like

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@smoke and @positive")
public class RunCucumberTest {}
```

> Another way to manage the tags by JVM System Property

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke and @positive"
```

> Option `--scenario` or pattern `file.feature:line` is a way to run a subset of scenarios

Ref: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1955
Here the Changelog of 5.7.0
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

-Dcucumber.filter.tags="(@smoke or @dry)"
You can also use
-Dcucumber.filter.tags="(@smoke or @dry) and not @positive".

Add this to CucumberOption to run the tags from your test runner class:
tags = "(@smoke or @dry)"

or

tags = "(@smoke or @dry) and not @positive"